# adding html in correct position of document using java script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, append, prepend

I've written this code for this purpose: I want to have a form for search, whenever the user clicked on the delete bottom all the html tages in that row must be deleted (the whole div) and whenever they click on the add word bottom another group of field for search must be added. the same for add group bottom. after clicking on add group bottom all the field set should repeat and by the next click again and again. now the problem is where to add and what to delete!! as you see the form is copying and its out of my control to delete or add what I want ( for example after clicking on delete bottom on the first row just the first row must go away not others. I hope I am clear. is there any solution?

```
<form action="search1.php" method="post">
    <fieldset style="width:50%;" id="g1">
        <legend>search form</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="border-left:1px solid #000">
                    <select name="opration" size="1">
                        <option>AND</option>
                        <option>OR</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="w2">
                        <input type="text" name="textfield" placeholder="search here" />
                        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" onclick="DoDelete()" /> synonimes
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkfield" onchange="DoAlert()" />
                    </div>
                    </br>
                    <div id="w1">
                        <input type="text" name="textfield" placeholder="search here" />
                        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" onclick="DoDelete()" /> synonime
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkfield" />
                    </div>
                    </br>
                    <input type="submit" name="addw" value="add word" onclick="DoAddW()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="addg" value="add group" onclick="DoAddG()" />
    </br>
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" />
</form>
<script>
    function DoDelete() {
        $("w1").remove();
    }

    function DoAddW() {
        alert("add word");
        $("#w").append(" </br><div id='w1'><input type='text' name='textfield' placeholder='search here'/><input type='submit' name='delete'  value='delete' onclick='DoDelete()'/>synonime<input type='checkbox' name='checkfield' /> </div></br> ");
    }

    function DoAddG() {
            alert("add group");
            $("#g").append(" <fieldset style='width:50%;' id='g1'><legend>serach form</legend><table><tr><td style='border-left:1px solid #000'><select name='opration' size='1'><option>AND</option><option>OR</option>/select></td><td><div id='w1'><input type='text' name='textfield' placeholder='search here' /><input type='submit' name='delete'  value='delete' onclick='DoDelete()'/>synonime<input type='checkbox' name='checkfield' /></div></br><input type='submit' name='addw' value='add word' onclick='DoAddW()'/></td></tr></table></fieldset>
                ");
            }

            function DoAlert() {
                alert("I want to add some synonimes")
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 function DoDelete(){
 $(this).closest('div').remove();
}
```

Add id to the td which contains W like this

```html
<td id="forW">
<div id="w2">
                    <input type="text" name="textfield" placeholder="search here" />
                    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" onclick="DoDelete()" /> synonimes
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkfield" onchange="DoAlert()" />
                </div>
 </td>
```

```
function DoAddW() {
    alert("add word");
    $("#forW").append(" </br><div id='w1'><input type='text' name='textfield' placeholder='search here'/><input type='submit' name='delete'  value='delete' onclick='DoDelete()'/>synonime<input type='checkbox' name='checkfield' /> </div></br> ");
}
```

Comment: I wish it worked but doesn't worked! what about adding?

Comment: you need to tell exactly where  you need add exactly

Comment: actually add is not important when the add word bottom is clicked the whole div must be add after the fields. just should not go to another group (I mean the fieldset must be the same)

Comment: i've edited the answer you need to give the td an id and the do it the way i've in my answer. check the edit!

Comment: it does not have flexibility for the next ones.

Comment: YOur exact need is not clear, for any further help you need to be very clear and tell me exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should try including the element which you click in the javascript methods you invoke in the onClick event.

```
  <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" onclick="DoDelete(this)" />
```

In your action methods you are specifying the element in which you perform the action instead of making them flexible for using them in any element.